# Does "Advanced Query Planning" in SDK 1.5.2 mean I no longer need to specify indexes in a datastore-indexes.xml file?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, indexing

What is the practical effect of the announcement of "Advanced Query Planning" in the latest App Engine 1.5.2 release?

> Advanced Query Planning - We are removing the need for exploding indexes 
>   and reducing the custom index requirements for many queries. The SDK will 
>   suggest better indexes in several cases and an upcoming article will describe 
>   what further optimizations are possible.

If I normally [would define my indexes like so](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datastore-indexes
  autoGenerate="true">
    <datastore-index kind="Employee" ancestor="false">
        <property name="lastName" direction="asc" />
        <property name="hireDate" direction="desc" />
    </datastore-index>

    <datastore-index kind="Project" ancestor="false">
        <property name="dueDate" direction="asc" />
    </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

Does this new SDK change mean I no longer need to include this file - and the App Engine runtime will automatically figure out what indexes are needed?

If so this sounds really cool!

Answer (score 3):

No. Advanced query planning means the App Engine runtime will be able to make better use of the built-in and composite (user-defined) indexes to execute a wider variety of queries. This may mean that some queries that previously required a composite index will now be executable without one (with some performance impact, which may or may not matter depending on your situation), but it doesn't eliminate the need for custom indexes.

Keep an eye out for a blog post or article with details in the very near future.